# libdl.so not found on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: dll, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to Ubuntu and am running Ubuntu in the Amazon EC2 cloud.

I am trying to compile `cppunit` on the Ubuntu boxes (`i386` and `amd64`) and it will not link to `libdl`

```
g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/DllPlugInTester DllPlugInTester.o CommandLineParser.o  -ldl ../../src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.so -lm  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/home/ubuntu/cppunit/lib
../../src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
../../src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
../../src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

Now I don't understand as `libdl.so` is present and correct at:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-98-1A:~/cppunit$ ls /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl*
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

But `whereis` has nothing:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-98-1A:~/cppunit$ whereis libdl
libdl:
```

`libc6` is installed:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-98-1A:~/cppunit$ sudo apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So why can my build not find it?

The `uname -r` is `3.2.0-25-virtual`

*"Normal"* `whereis` on Fedora looks like this:

```
[matt cppunit] whereis libdl
libdl: /lib/libdl.so /usr/lib/libdl.so /lib64/libdl.so /usr/lib64/libdl.so
```

Any ideas?

*Edit*: My `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` seems sensible:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-98-1A:~$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
# Multiarch support
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# This directive teaches ldconfig to search in nosegneg subdirectories
# and cache the DSOs there with extra bit 1 set in their hwcap match
# fields. In Xen guest kernels, the vDSO tells the dynamic linker to
# search in nosegneg subdirectories and to match this extra hwcap bit
# in the ld.so.cache file.
hwcap 1 nosegneg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also ran into this on 64bit ubuntu, gcc 4.6.3, my hunch was the ordering of link lib. However, the same thing builds on 32bit.
I added -ldl at the end of the link command and it linked, so looks like some sort of linker issue.
You can also set env var: LIBS=-ldl, from shell and it will build.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what we found too.  Seriously odd that it works in 32bit but not 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Because ld.so.conf is for the dynamic linker, not the post-assembly linker, ld(1).  Someone created this new path, but did not update the directories that the linker searches.  there should be a link in /lib64 or /usr/lib64 for libdl, or one of the the paths that the linker searches for linking 64bit objects.

This (new path) is another example, from my PoV, of random changes that various Linux distros make without fully understanding the consequences or history.